# Powershell can't run *.exe, Cursorpositionerror

Tags: powershell, error-handling, cmd

Lately, I came across weird error for which I cannot find a solution. A parent script, executed by our vendor during automation patching, contains the line:

```bash
cmd.exe /c <command>
```

It throws the following error.

```
PS>TerminatingError(): "Program 'cmd.exe' failed to run: The CursorPosition property is not implemented by PsSasRawUserInterface.At <pathToScript>.ps1:105 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c "RiposteService Stop"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~."
Program 'cmd.exe' failed to run: The CursorPosition property is not implemented by PsSasRawUserInterface.At 
<pathToScript>.ps1:105 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c "RiposteService Stop"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At <pathToScript>.ps1:105 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c "RiposteService Stop"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
Program 'cmd.exe' failed to run: The CursorPosition property is not
implemented by PsSasRawUserInterface.At <pathToScript>.ps1:105 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c "RiposteService Stop"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At <pathToScript>.ps1:105 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c "RiposteService Stop"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Expected output is output of cmd run.

When executed from a Powershell Prompt, I cannot replicate the issue.

Does anyone know what the cause could be here?

I've also tried to replace cmd.exe directly with called executable with same result.

Comment: I'm not fully familiar with process of execution but from the observation it seems that script is executed by service like HPSM. All other commands in script run without issue. Issue is only when executable is invoked (cmd.exe or Riposte.exe in this case). As mentioned in description. I replace `cmd /c` directly with `RiposteService Stop` yet with same result. I'm also using Transcript to save script run as log.

Comment: OK, looking at Transcript header it seems that script is not executed by Windows powershell rather than with some embedded Powershell `Host Application: C:\Program Files\Opsware\agent\bin\PsSasHost.exe /nologo /script c:\windows\temp\temp2959990302.ps1` which I guess is causing this issue. Could there be that some library/assembly is just not loaded which then preventing *.exe files from being correctly executed?

Comment: Not a solution as it seems that PsSasHost is missing either some assembly or some implementation since when testing I keep getting `The CursorPosition property is not implemented by  PsSasRawUserInterface` but as workaround it's sufficient to store result of execution in variable e.g. `$result = RiposteService Stop`. Which works and exe gets executed. @Mofi Unless you have other idea/suggestion how this can be fixed, I will answer this issue with workaround solution.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comments, which includes your own findings:

- As an aside: There is no need to call `RiposteService stop` via `cmd /c` - invoking it directly is sufficient.
- Your script executes in a custom [PowerShell host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost) rather than in a regular console window.
- Seemingly, this custom host doesn't implement all features that the `ConsoleHost` PowerShell host used in console windows does, notably including cursor-related features ([`.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.cursorposition#system-management-automation-host-pshostrawuserinterface-cursorposition)) that `RiposteService` relies on when its output streams *aren't* captured.
- The workaround - which may be the better solution anyway - is therefore to *capture* the streams:

  ```
  # Capture - and discard - only the stdout stream
  $null = RiposteService stop

  # Capture - and discard - *all* streams (both stdout and stderr)
  RiposteService stop *> $null
  ```

  - However, instead of *discarding* the output, you may want to *log* it somewhere, say with `*>> c:\path\to\some.log`
  - Also, you may want to test if the program *signaled* failure via its exit code, using the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).